# NoMethodError in LineItemsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with the Agile Web Development with Rails (4th edition) book and I bumped into a piece of code that is not working. I tried hard to figure out why it's not working, but I didn't make it.

BACKGROUD INFORMATION

The following classes are involved:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private

  def current_cart
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  end
end
```

NOW
here is where it fails:

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @line_items = LineItem.all`

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @line_items }
    end
  end

  # GET /line_items/1
  # GET /line_items/1.xml
  def show
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item }
    end
  end

  # GET /line_items/new
  # GET /line_items/new.xml
  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item }
    end
  end

  # GET /line_items/1/edit
  def edit
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /line_items
  # POST /line_items.xml
  def create
    @cart = current_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = **@cart.line_items.build(:product => product)**`
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**
*NoMethodError in LineItemsController#create
undefined method `line_items' for 9:Fixnum
Rails.root: /home/tmiskiew/depot*

*app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:53:in `create'
Request
Parameters:
{"product_id"=>"4",
 "authenticity_token"=>"dR4nL5zI+R7qIIPwNkl3EoaI1KyFWRokvh92m3PwD8o="}*

Anyone an idea what's wrong with @cart.line_items.build?
I'm working rails 3.0.9 and ruby 1.8.7

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your error
`undefined method line_items' for 9:Fixnum`

This says that @cart is a number, not an Cart object (`@cart = current_cart` from create action returns a number),
`current_cart` function returns a number because
Cart.find(session[:cart_id]) returns `recordNotFound` and your `rescue` block from `current_cart` function will be executed.

Remember that every function in Ruby returns the result of the last executed line, so you will get returned the cart.id

Edit: For first comment, try to rewrite method

```
    def current_cart
      Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        cart = Cart.create
        session[:cart_id] = cart.id
        cart # this will get returned
      end
    end
```

Comment: Do you mean I have to finish the else branch of current_cart with return session? I tried that, but I'm now getting SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: INSERT INTO "carts" ("updated_at", "created_at") VALUES ('2011-08-04 07:51:23.552125', '2011-08-04 07:51:23.552125')

Comment: Return session instead of cart, because of the code that follows is:

`    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart,
          :notice => 'Line item was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item,
          :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.errors,
          :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end`

Comment: You can return `cart` and can use what you put in session[:cart_id] like this `@cart = current_cart` and call `@cart.id`, this will give you the exact value like session[:cart_id] (after all you put in session cart.id)

Comment: After changing to return cart or just cart I'm getting "Cannot redirect to nil!" error. ActionController::ActionControllerError in LineItemsController#create

Comment: paste the entire `create` action please

Comment: `def create
  @cart = current_cart
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.line_items.create(:product => product)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart,
        :notice => 'Line item was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item,
        :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.errors,
        :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end`

Comment: The dump says
rack.session: {"_csrf_token"=>"dR4nL5zI+R7qIIPwNkl3EoaI1KyFWRokvh92m3PwD8o=", "session_id"=>"3aeb934eb93414bca6b4930c50138d90", "cart_id"=>15, "flash"=>{:notice=>"Line item was successfully created."}}
rack.session.options: {:httponly=>true, :secure=>false, :expire_after=>nil, :path=>"/", :domain=>nil, :id=>"3aeb934eb93414bca6b4930c50138d90"}
rack.url_scheme: "http"
rack.version: [1, 1]

Comment: You call `@cart.line_items.create`. Create method `Creates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass`. Then you call @line_item.save -> I think @line_item is already saved. Before respond_to block try this `puts @line_item.cart`. Hope that cart is not nil

Comment: I've changed

`@cart.line_items.create` to `@cart.line_items.build` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I fixed it...hope it works for you too.

**/app/models/cart.rb:**

```
def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
    end
    return current_item
end
```

Add the return in. I'm not 100% sure why this was failing, but I think the function only returns the quantity, rather than a line item unless the `if` statement evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar error, it turns out I have a typo in Cart.rb:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

typo in :destory... and it cause the undefined method... hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and I felt really stuck on it.
I fixed it by rollbacking the database and migrating it again.

Commands on terminal:

- rake db:rollback
- rake db:migrate